On what basis do some translators place Romans 2:13-15 in parenthesis?
Several traditionally-oriented translations place Romans 2:13-15 in parentheses.

13 (For not the hearers of the law are just before God, but the doers
of the law shall be justified. 14 For when the Gentiles, which have
not the law, do by nature the things contained in the law, these,
having not the law, are a law unto themselves: 15 Which shew the work
of the law written in their hearts, their conscience also bearing
witness, and their thoughts the mean while accusing or else excusing
one another;)  - KJV

The strong majority of modern translators do not offset these verses. I am wondering about the basis for treating them parenthetically. Is it based on manuscript traditions or an editorial decision of early Protestant translators who may have felt that these verses are hard to reconcile with the doctrine of salvation through faith in Jesus, as opposed to following one's inner conscience? Or is there some other explanation?

It is nothing to do with textual matters - it is purely an interpretive matter.

Looking at the text, I can see one possible grammatical reason.
vv13-15 are explaining the second statement in v12, so they are needed as part of Paul's argument.
But possibly the AV translators were reading "... in the day when God shall judge the secrets of men" (v16) as a continuation of the sentence ending "shall be judged by the law" in v12.
If they are right, then the explanation is actually awkwardly inserted into the middle of a sentence (which might be explained by Paul's practice of dictation). Something a modern writer might have added as a footnote at the bottom of the page. Given that reading, they might then have thought that adding the parentheses would make it easier for the reader to see the shape of the argument.


1 Thanks... I see a number of commentaries now, addressing this question. https://biblehub.com/commentaries/romans/2-13.htm


The answer is quite simple. The answer lies in the fact that most people don't understand the context of Romans 1 through 8. The gentile that Paul mentions in the second chapter of Romans is not a heathen or idol worshiper or an non-believer. If you start at the last few verse of chapter 2 we find that the identity of
the  uncircumcised in rom 2.14 and 27 is identified in verses 28 and 29.
That identity being the converted believing uncircumcised Gentile
So starting from 2.14 all the way to the end of the chapter that Gentile is the converted believing uncircumcised Gentile.
Who has God's laws written in their hearts jer 31,31 the new covenant believers.i will put my laws in their inward parts and write in in their hearts.
You see Pauls ministry was to the gentiles whom he taught that adherence to Moses law of ceremonies,rituals sacrifices and circumstances were no longer valid in the new covenant.acts 21.21
But the believing Jews did not understand that Moses law was abolished at the cross and a new covenant was initiated   So they continued as believers in  sacrifices,rituals , circumcision, ceremonies and temple worship .
Rom 2 as well as 1 through 8 is all about teaching the believing Jews that righteousness no longer comes by the works of the law or as he says in rom 3 20 an 27 the deeds of the law which are ceremonies,rituals, sacrifices circumcision,temple worship.
That these believing uncircumcised Gentiles in the new covenant are righteous before God more than you because they are keeping the moral code rom 2.14 and your breaking it Rom 2.5 and 23.
Why are the Gentiles keeping the moral code in 2.14 because in 28 and 2 on that Gentile is a Jew inwardly who's circumcision of the heart whose praise is of God
That's the description of a believing Gentle not an unbelieving Gentile.
That's what's not being taught in most churches

Welcome to the group Caporale... And thanks.... but I don't see how this answer the question as to why the KJV places these verses in parentheses.

This answer needs to explicitly state whether the parentheses should be there, and why.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It's hard to say why the translator put them there abviously they thought it would help the reader understand the passage better. But my understanding of the passage doesn't rely on the parenthesies.

"my understanding of the passage doesn't rely on the parenthesies" — Yet the surrounding scripture has a completely different meaning depending upon whether the parentheses are there. Does it mean (without parentheses): "their thoughts accusing or else excusing them in the day when God …" or mean (with parentheses): "as many as have sinned in the law will be judged by the law in the day when God …"? That is the key issue here.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
